# google is undefined error while using charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Trying to display statistics as per table data.
I want to use google charts, but there is a google is not defined error. Only the data in the HTML part is displayed. The necessary bar chart is not displayed.
The code works fine on jsfiddle.The code is as below:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Days', 'Service', 'Incident', 'Others'],
              ['1-10 Days', 10, 6, 4],
              ['11-20 Days', 0, 0, 2],
              ['21-30 Days', 0, 4, 4]
            ]);

            var options = {
              chart: {
                title: 'TAT CHART',
                subtitle: 'Service, Incident, and Others',
              },
              bars: 'vertical',
              vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
              height: 300,
              colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
            var selection = chart.getSelection();
            
            if (selection.length) {
           
                var row = selection[0].row;
                document.querySelector('#myValueHolder').innerHTML = data.getValue(row, 1);
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            }
        });
          
          }
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
        <br/>
        
        <div id="disp_table">
            <table class="display" style="width:50%;">
                <thead>
                    <th>Days</th>
                    <th>Service</th>
                    <th>Incident</th>
                    <th>Others</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($plot); $i++) {?>
                        <tr>
                             <td><?php echo $plot[$i][0]['days']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $plot[$i][0]['service']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $plot[$i][0]['incident']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $plot[$i][0]['other']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table/>
```

Trying to display statistics as per table data.
I want to use google charts, but there is a google is not defined error. Only the data in the HTML part is displayed. The necessary bar chart is not displayed.
The code works fine on jsfiddle.The code is as below:

Comment: sounds like the script library hasn't been added to the page --> `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`